# Chained select in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a chained select on my form but i cannot just do it in bootstrap, and im wondering if my code is wrong or not, i am following the code in this site http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

and tried to put it in my code, its yet on proper form but here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    include('connect.php');
    include('session.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap Autocomplete</title>
<meta name="viewport" content='width=700' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <link href="dp/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="dp/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="text.css.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- font Awesome -->
    <link href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="../../css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- DATA TABLES -->
    <link href="../../css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="../../css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/typeahead.js"></script> 
<style type='text/css'>
/* regular css */
.tabs {
    padding: 10px 2em
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
/* applies only if the screen is narrower than 500px */
.tabs {
    padding: 3px 1em
}
}
input, textarea {
    max-width:100%
}
WebFont.load({
google: {
    families: ['Open Sans']
}
});

.header {
    font-family: Arial
}
.wf-opensans-n4-active .header {
    font-family: 'Open Sans'
}
</style>

</head>
<body class="skin-blue">
    <select id="branch" name="branch">
        <option>
        <?php
        $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from branch")or die(mysql_error);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                echo "<option value=".$row["branch_id"]." class=".$row["branch_id"].">" .$row["branch_name"]. "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </option>
    </select>
<select id="service" name="service">
    <option>
        <?php
        $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from service")or die(mysql_error);
            while($row =    mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                echo "<option   value=".$row["service_id"]." class=".$row["branch_id"].">" .$row["service_name"]. "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </option>
</select>
<script>
    $("#service").chained("#branch"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); */
</script>
```

I put it on the top to see if its functioning but it's not?

The working code is here, no bootstrap just plain HTML,

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include('connect.php'); ?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="branch" name="branch">
        <option>
        <?php
        $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from branch")or die(mysql_error);
            while($row =   mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                echo "<option value=".$row["branch_id"]." class=".$row["branch_id"].">" .$row["branch_name"]. "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </option>
    </select>

    <select id="service" name="service">
        <option>
        <?php
        $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from service")or die(mysql_error);
            while($row =   mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                echo "<option    value=".$row["service_id"]." class=".$row["branch_id"].">"   .$row["service_name"]. "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </option>
    </select>
<script>
    $("#service").chained("#branch"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); */
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've searched every chained select but I just cant make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you said `Chained select` is working 2nd code example when there is no bootstrap reason you have jQuery library first

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
```

and the reason `Chained select` is not working in first code example because right after `meta` you have this JS library in following sequence

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
```

Notice above that jQuery library is placed second after `bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js` and if you check browser console log you will see errors saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

and this is really a mess

```
<!-- datepicker -->
<link href="dp/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="dp/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
<link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="text.css.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- font Awesome -->
<link href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link href="../../css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- DATA TABLES -->
<link href="../../css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="../../css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you have 2 `bootstrap.min.css` so remove one and you have included `bootstrap.js` as stylesheet link `<link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Remember **jQuery library always comes first** so put jQuery library at top and then `bootstrap library` and also include first all `CSS` and then all `JS` libraries as following.

```
<!-- CSS -->

<link href="dp/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="dp/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="text.css.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- JS -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's fix the `<select>` elements. you have `<option></option>` inside `<option></option>` and you are missing quotes `'`

```
<select id="service" name="service">
    <option>
    <?php
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from service")or die(mysql_error);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
            echo "<option  value=".$row["service_id"]." class=".$row["branch_id"].">".$row["service_name"]."</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </option>
</select>
```

so remove `<option></option>` before and after `query` and mixing PHP with HTML is not good practice so do like this

```
<select id="service" name="service">
    <?php
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from service")or die(mysql_error);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
    ?>
    <option  value="<?php echo $row["service_id"];?>" class="<?php echo $row["branch_id"];?>"><?php echo $row["service_name"];?></option>
    <?php } ?>        
</select>
```

make same change in other `<select>` element too.

and last make script DOM ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#service").chained("#branch"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); */
});
</script>
```

**Note:**

1. Always check browser console log for errors.
2. `MySQL` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), start using [MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I think it will help people like me

Chaining select box can be easily done using jQuery. This is what I did.

HTML

```
<select id=select_1>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id=select_2>
  <option>2-1</option>
  <option>2-2</option>
  <option>2-3</option>
</select>

<select id=select_3>
  <option>3-1</option>
  <option>3-2</option>
  <option>3-3</option>
</select>
```

Now the jQuery part. All you have to do is trigger change method when one of the select is change.

```
$('#select_1').on('change', function(){
    $('#select_2').val(1).trigger('change'); //change value of second select and trigger change function
});
$('#sub_category').on('change', function(){
    $('#select_3').val('2);
});
</script>
```

Thats it. 
Cheers